# How to align TextView to center of the screen, and ImageView to stick next to it?

Tags: android, xml, alignment, android-imageview, textview

This is how app looks like now for longer text in TextView:

[image]

Here is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.hpuser.weatherapp.MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
            android:id="@+id/textViewCity"
            android:layout_width="158dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1.40"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAlignment="textEnd"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTemperature"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 Celsius deg"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.32"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.58"
        android:paddingTop="40dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewWind"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:text="Wind speed [mps]"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewWindValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewClouds"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="Cloudiness  [%]"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewCloudsValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewSunrise"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="Sunrise"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSunriseValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/textViewSunset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".25"
                android:text="Sunset"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewSunsetValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want name of city to be centered, and ImageView to stick to it because it refers to changing name of city.
It looks OK for smaller text, but for larger, everything goes to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your Linear layout with Relative layout as shown below, using torightof attribute we can make sure the image always stays to the right.

Layout_centerHorizontal makes it always align to the center of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:id="@+id/textViewCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="logng_name_here"
        **android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"**
        android:textSize="24sp"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPen"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit"
        **android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textViewCity"**
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! It works perfectly and your explanation is good and easy to understand.

Comment: Glad it helped.